# What does :/ mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Very basic question here - We are asked to translate the following to the new format, so

```
"hello".send(:reverse)
```

becomes

```
"hello".reverse
```

What does the `:/` mean in the following?

```
10.send(:/, 3)
=> 3
```

Comment: Generally `:`-anything thing means "symbol". In this case, it's read as "*symbol-slash*". The syntax allows for a wide variety of these, like `:+` and `:?` but in general terms `:x` is equivalent to `"x".to_sym` for a large variety of `x` type terms.

Comment: It means you are annoyed lol (please forgive me :D )

Comment: `:-)` `:-D` `:'-(` `:-o` `:-<` `:-s` `:->` `:~-(` `:-0` `:-e` `):-(`

Comment: @sawa Nice symbols... Lollz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a method like [`Fixnum#/`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-2F). [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-send) method takes it first argument as method name, which can be either a *symbol* or *string*.

So you are doing division operation by using `10.send(:/, 3)`, which is nothing but `10/3` (which is a syntactic sugar of `10./(3)`).

Comment: By way of comparison, `10.send(:divmod, 3)` is equivalent to `10.divmod(3)` in the same way `10.send(:/, 3)` is equivalent to `10./(3)`, which is equivalent to `10 / 3`.